# Use variable defined in config.rb in scss files

Tags: css, ruby, compass-sass, sass

Is it possible to use a variable defined in the config.rb file of a compass project, throughout the SCSS files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your config.rb file add a custom module:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def custom_color(value)
    rgb = options[:custom][:custom_colors][value.to_s].scan(/^#?(..?)(..?)(..?)$/).first.map {|a| a.ljust(2, a).to_i(16)}
    Sass::Script::Color.new(rgb)
  end
end
```

And then set up your variables (again, in the config.rb file):

```
sass_options = {:custom => { :custom_colors => {"main" => "#ff1122"} } }
```

Then in your scss file, you can use the `custom_color()` function:

```
body {
  background-color: custom_color(main);
}
```

You could also write another custom function which returns other types such as font sizes, measurements, etc. by passing in strings, and then returning the appropriate class instance.

Interestingly, this would allow you to pass in environment variables into the compass command line, and that would generate different results.

So if you sass_options are:

```
sass_options = {:custom => { :custom_colors => {"main" => ENV["MAIN_COLOR"]} } }
```

And you run compass:

```
MAIN_COLOR=#dd1122 bundle exec compass compile
```

Then whatever color you pass in on the command line will appear in the resultant css. If you're using Heroku, you could `heroku config:set MAIN_COLOR=#224411` and be able to set template colors on a per-app basis, using the same scss files.

Comment: Interesting, what's the advantage of this over just defining the colors in a base Sass file that's imported?

Comment: You could pass in environment variables into compass that then generates a set of different css files based on a varying palette?

Comment: What is the meaning and purpose of "sass_options = {:custom => { :custom_colors => {"main" => "#ff1122"} } }" ?