# Set SASS variable depending on compass environment

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

Depending on if compass is called with the :production or the :configuration profile(see [sass configuration reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/)), I want to set the SASS-Variable $debug to true or false.

Here is what I came up with:
config.rb:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def development_environment()
    Sass::Script::Bool.new(environment == :development)
  end

  declare :development_environment, :args => []
end

sass_options = {:custom => { :development_environment => {} } }
```

_base.scss:

```
$debug: development_environment();
```

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: Duplicate entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506578/use-variable-defined-in-config-rb-in-scss-files

Comment: Do you get an error or …?