# SASS::Script::Color not being interpreted as a color by some SASS functions

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I've recently decided I want to have some default actions that run when my SASS is compiled and found this stack overflow question which helped me write a function to do it ([Use variable defined in config.rb in scss files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506578/use-variable-defined-in-config-rb-in-scss-files))

The colour value gets pulled through fine and is treated like a SASS color object (i.e. if I pass '#ff0000' into the function it comes out as 'red' which is fine) but it doesn't work in the tint() and shade() functions.

The error I get is

> (Line 137: "#ff1122" is not a color for 'shade')

But if I comment out all of the instances of tint() and shade() then it works perfectly.

Here's all the code that's being used:

config.rb (taken from the stack overflow link up there mentioned before)

```
sass_options = {:custom => { :custom_colors => {"main" => "#ff1122"} } }

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def custom_color(value)
    rgb = options[:custom][:custom_colors][value.to_s].scan(/^#?(..?)(..?)(..?)$/).first.map {|a| a.ljust(2, a).to_i(16)}
    Sass::Script::Color.new(rgb)
  end
end
```

style.scss (line 5)

```
$col_primary : #{custom_color(main)};
```

style.scss (line 137 that was mentioned in the error)

```
@include background-with-css2-fallback(linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 51%, shade($col_primary, 10) 50%, $col_primary 75%, $col_primary 0%));
```

I can't see a reason that this wouldn't work as it works as a colour elsewhere.

I can give more info if needed

Comment: If there isn't a real solution for this, you could use mix instead of tint/shade, since all those functions really do is mix the specified color with white/black.

Comment: I get the same error when using mix - I guess it makes sense as it's probably just using that function internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being this

```
$col_primary : #{custom_color(main)};
```

Which I took from the example - I think SASS interprets that as a string and so it doesn't matter that the function is returning the correct type.