# Configure SCSS using web.config

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio-2015, sass

Is there any way to set a variable in _Settings.scss from a setting in web.config.

We use different environments which require to at least differentiate between dev and live where to find the cdn path or use local files.

Comment: From the config.rb is possible as detailed in this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506578/use-variable-defined-in-config-rb-in-scss-files

Comment: How would that work with web.config. We're not using Compas currently but if we did, how could we update the config.rb depending on the environment being deployed to. The reason we want it to be updated from the web.config file is because of the transformation feature.